# Only one attribute for each element in an XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

Below you can find a portion of an XSD:

```
<xs:element name="MyElement" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="MyChildElement">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:attribute name="MyAttribute1" type="xs:decimal" use="optional" />
                    <xs:attribute name="MyAttribute2" type="xs:decimal" use="optional" />
                    <xs:attribute name="MyAttribute3" type="xs:decimal" use="optional" />
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

It accepts both these XMLs:

```
<MyElement>
    <MyChildElement MyAttribute1="10" />
    <MyChildElement MyAttribute2="10" />
</MyElement>

<MyElement>
    <MyChildElement MyAttribute1="10" MyAttribute2="10" MyAttribute3="10" />
</MyElement>
```

I would like to know if there is a way to force the XSD to accept only the first one,
that is only one attribute for each element.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no explicit way to express any special conditions on the presence of particular attributes in relation with others.

(After all, attributes are supposed to express things inherent to the entity
expressed by the element.
For instance, is it possible that a person has a nose only on condition he doesn't have ears?)

So, in XSD 1.0 it is straight impossible.

In XSD 1.1 there is `<xs:assert>` element that can be added in a complexType to check
something special about it (and about attributes in particular).
Then, some XPath expression might be written to test your condition
(for instance, that `MyAttribute1="10" MyAttribute2="10"` is invalid).

But another problem is that very few tools support XSD 1.1 now.

What's more, if you've got such a condition on those attribute, I think, the situation
is exactly ripe to express the same things as child elements (with simple content).
Then, XSD has all the means to constrain those children!

Answer (score 1):

Not in XSD 1.0. In XSD 1.1 you can do it using assertions. XSD 1.1 is currently supported only in Saxon and Xerces.